# PowerShell XML Nodes from Another File

Tags: xml, powershell, nodes

I'm running my PowerShell script to basically create a big XML file from several smaller XML files.

The script opens Template.txt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Model>
  <LobSystems>
    <LobSystem>
      <LobSystemInstances>
      </LobSystemInstances>  
      <Entities>
        <!-- individual <ENTITY> from every XML file goes here -->
      </Entities>      
    </LobSystem>
  </LobSystems>
</Model>
```

All I want to do is to copy the node `<Entity>` from each XML file in a given folder and create a new MASTER.XML using the template and information and extracting `<ENTITY>` from every .xml in the folder, resulting this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Model>
  <LobSystems>
    <LobSystem>
      <LobSystemInstances>
      </LobSystemInstances>  
      <Entities>

          <Entity Name="A">       // from File1.XML
             <Value>XYZ</Value>
          </Entity>

          <Entity Name="B">       // from File4.XML
             <Value>123</Value>
          </Entity>

          <Entity Name="C">       // from File3.XML
             <Value>@#$</Value>
          </Entity>

      </Entities>      
    </LobSystem>
  </LobSystems>
</Model>
```

So far my script is the following:

```
[xml]$master = get-content .\Template.txt
$files = get-item -Path .\*.xml -Exclude 'Master.xml'

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    [xml]$filecontents = get-content $file

    $entity = $fileContents.Model.LobSystems.LobSystem.Entities.Entity  

    $master.Model.LobSystems.LobSystem.Entities.Entity.AppendChild($entity);

}
$master.Save("Master.xml")
```

Well it is not working.... I keep getting error messages about AppendChild()

Any suggestions???

Comment: I suggest: define *not working...*, include error messages in your post.

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At Parser.ps1:17 char:5
+     $master.Model.LobSystems.LobSystem.Entities.Entity.AppendChild($importedEnti ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you need to [import](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the element first since it comes from another XML document instance, something like this :

```
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    [xml]$filecontents = get-content $file

    $entity = $fileContents.Model.LobSystems.LobSystem.Entities.Entity  

    $importedEntity = $master.ImportNode($entity, $TRUE)

    $master.Model.LobSystems.LobSystem.Entities.AppendChild($importedEntity);

}
```

Comment: Wondeful!!!! Got me the right thing working, but I had to remove one little mistake, instead of Entities.Entity. simply removed .Entity and everything worked fine!

Comment: Sure, `AppendChild()` should've been invoked on the parent of `Entity`. Thanks for the confirmation and correction, answer has been updated accordingly.